# Getting date by Year and Week number and get Week Number and Year Number back

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to generate date by year, week and day number i.e

```
let date = moment().year(2019).isoWeek(1).isoWeekday(1).toDate(); 
//Mon Dec 31 2018 11:56:45 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

the problem i'm facing when i want to get year and week from this generated date

```
moment(date).year() //2018 
moment(date).isoWeek() // 1
```

NOT SURE HOW TO SOLVE THIS

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation about year accessors](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/year/) and you will find the [Week Year (ISO)](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-week-year/) section:

```
moment(date).isoWeekYear() // 2019
```

Comment: awesome! its helped me a lot